# Pre-text (cover, dedicatory, table of contents, list of figures) printed one-sided, rest two-sided

Tags: table-of-contents, double-sided

My thesis commitee demands that the pre-text elements, including table of contents, list of figures, list of algorithms goes only on the odd pages, with the body of the thesis go two-sided, with new chapters initiating on odd pages. I do almost all, except by the lists. How can I get the toc, lof, loa, lot to go only in odd pages?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work, at least with the `book` class:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{afterpage,emptypage}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % mock text

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\afterpage{\afterpage{\cleardoublepage}}
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\afterpage{\afterpage{\cleardoublepage}}
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\afterpage{\afterpage{\cleardoublepage}}
\listoftables

\mainmatter
\afterpage{}

\def\mock{
  \chapter{A}
  \section{B}
  \kant[1]
  \begin{figure}\caption{F}\end{figure}
  \kant[2]
  \begin{table}\caption{T}\end{table}
  \kant[3]
  \section{B}
  \kant[1]
  \begin{figure}\caption{F}\end{figure}
  \kant[2]
  \begin{table}\caption{T}\end{table}
  \kant[3]
  \section{B}
  \kant[1]
  \begin{figure}\caption{F}\end{figure}
  \kant[2]
  \begin{table}\caption{T}\end{table}
  \kant[3]
}
\def\fivemock{\mock\mock\mock\mock\mock}
\fivemock\fivemock

\end{document}
```